# What are the bad points of the iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

I'm thinking of buying an iPod Touch. But first I'd like to know what its bad points are so I can decide better if it's suitable for me and if I can find better alternatives.

The reason why I'm considering the iPod Touch is because I want a device that is not a phone, I can listen to music and podcasts while walking, and it has a browser (wireless connection is fine) on which I can quickly check news and tweets. Perhaps I should add that this would be my first Apple product.

So I'd like to learn from your experience. What don't you like about an iPod Touch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you're using Windows, you're basically locked into using iTunes to manage your content; some people don't like iTunes.
- Syncing non-media content is weird, too. There isn't a unified sync system. I sync calendar via Google Calendar, notes via SimpleNote, and general files with Dropbox. Some apps only sync with your computer over WiFi, which is a hassle for me at work where the wireless network is not set to permit this. Sync is really important for the iPod Touch because it's nice to have a lot of your data at hand all the time, but it's a pain to type it in manually because it's so small.
- You can't easily update podcasts on the device. I couldn't sync for one week one time and had to update each episode by finding it in the iTunes store.
- It's really smooth, so if your hands are greasy it's easy to drop. Mine has handled drops well. I'm glad I use plastic screen protectors, though.

These are the most potent drawbacks I could come up with. I haven't found any comparable devices that solve these problems any better, though. Non-phone smart devices that fit in your pocket that aren't iPod Touches basically don't exist now; there are some Android devices in the works. I'm delighted by my iPod Touch and absolutely recommend the device.

Comment: Great list! That is certainly very useful to know.

Comment: If you're using Windows, MediaMonkey is a serious alternative to iTunes to manage your music

Answer (score 8):

Look at it this way. If you want to play games and use apps, browse the internet, all that jazz, you want the touch. If you want to carry every song you own and maybe some videos, get an iPod classic. If you are a jogger who only needs a few songs at a time, get a shuffle or nano.

Also, someone said it was slippery. This is correct. Get a case if you have a touch. I dropped my 2nd generation and shattered the screen when it hit at the corner. I have a 4th generation now and got a case for it just in case. The classic isn't as slippery, but it's always nice to have a case for any device you're going to be whipping around with you all the time.

Comment: Great classification! I was actually looking for something like that. Very good to know.

Comment: dont know if its just me, but the iPod touch 2g didnt sound as good as a classic ipod either

Answer (score 6):

No GPS and it doesn't vibrate :)

Other than that I think Apple has done a fantastic job on it. Make sure to get the latest one though.

Comment: Why the latest one? From what I've seen it just added some features that I'm not really interested in. Can you expand on that? What do you like of the latest version? What advantages does it have over the previous ones?

Comment: Mainly the retina display, Facetime, speed boost, HD video recording, gyroscope for more precise motion control & front camera makes self portraits easier. It's also thinner and very likely has little better battery life. With a lot of emphasis on the retina display, it's sooo nice.

Comment: Not to mention it added the built-in microphone.

Answer (score 5):

In my day to day usage I only found on thing missing wich is quite annoying and IMHO a design flaw: There is no mute/pause-resume button or any way to pause and resume the playback with one single click. You always have to get that device out of your pocket, turn the screen on, unlock the screen, go to they playback controls and press pause/play.

Batterylife is also an issue if you play games or run wifi enabled apps. But you won't find any other device that is better in that regard either.

Comment: Well you can do it in about 2 click from the home page, when locked, double tap the home button, then click on Pause. Another harsh way is to just pull out the headphones which cause an automatic pause.

Comment: Many headphones have play pause buttons whether it's Bluetooth or physical button. +1 for a good answer with several good points

Answer (score 2):

I own an iPod touch, and it is a cool device. The most useful feature it has, in my opinion, is the app which allows you to use it as a remote control for my Mac Mini when using iTunes. The screen is a bit small for most other activities, such as reading and typing. Therefore, based on what you wrote, I would suggest buying an iPad instead. I prefer my Kindle for reading. I plan to buy the new generation iPad so that I can comfortably browse the net while laying in bed or my couch. I can't stand typing on a small or touch screen, therefore I don't see my Macbook losing favor any time soon.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have stressed my priorities a bit. I'd like a device to carry on me so I can listen to music while walking, or waiting in queue. So the iPad is out of the question. Browsing is not as important. I was thinking of a quick look over the news or twitter. I'll change my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

After owning an iPhone 4 I really don't like the shiny case any more. It is way slimmer than the iPhone 3 and I just can't grip it or pick it up well since there is so little of it and it is very shiny and slippery.

Apart from that if you don't want 3G networking I don't see many disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is horrid at organising music (especially if you have an existing library not created using it), and slow too. It's a shame such good hardware is lumbered with a 3rd rate application. On Windows MediaMonkey is a viable alternative since it keeps pace with Apple's constant tinkering with the database structure of the iPod. If it wasn't for the Upnp apps like PlugPlayer, I wouldn't be so enamoured with mine.

Comment: That sounds like something you dislike about iTunes, not the iPod Touch.

Comment: Ditto, Dori! I'm thinkin' so too...

Answer (score 0):

I think the lack of a camera and Bluetooth make it much less useful.

The sort of all in one device that does everything but the phone is great.  But not quite there on the Touch yet.

Comment: The iPod Touch has a camera (both front- and rear-facing).

Comment: …and Bluetooth.

Comment: Ah, then I must be referring to the one my wife had, and not the latest build.  Great news!